# Microsoft Access SQL for selecting value based on closest date to specified date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table I need to query to find the price of an item, based on the date that price was entered and the date the item was ordered. I want to use the price that is closest to the order date. I have tried looking online and on here, but have not found anything that has worked properly. I also specify the item number as part of the query.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CSM400MFG_FCCSTHST
WHERE item_number = 'AARES02NS'
AND CSTDTE = DATEDIFF('d', CSTDTE, '2023/04/03')
```

This results in nothing showing up.

I also tried

```
SELECT CSTPN, CSTMTL, CSTDTE
FROM CSM400MFG_FCCSTHST
WHERE CSTPN = 'AARES02NS'
AND CSTDTE =  ABS(DATEDIFF('d','2023/04/03',CSTDTE));
```

This pulls all items that match the item number and does not limit it to the closest date. What I wanted it to return would be the price for date 3/30/2023 since that is only 3 days away from 4/3/2023 vs the 4/14 date
[Result of above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COgyO.png)

Comment: is it possible for you to post some sample data and also your expected result, thanks

Comment: have you tried instead of including the `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` use it as the `ORDER BY` ordered in descending order? then your first result should be what you're looking for

Comment: @Portal - I did, but it still pulls the whole list of prices and just sorts them with the most recent one on top and not the one with the closest date

Comment: @reiem87 seems like they should at least be in order from closest to furthest from your target date considering you take the absolute value

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
SELECT CSTPN
    ,CSTMTL
    ,CSTDTE
    ,ABS(DATEDIFF('d', '2023/04/03', CSTDTE)) AS DIFF
FROM CSM400MFG_FCCSTHST
WHERE CSTPN = 'AARES02NS'
ORDER BY DIFF LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CSM400MFG_FCCSTHST
WHERE item_number = 'AARES02NS'
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF('d', CSTDTE, #2023/04/03#))
```